# Excel: Transpose rows to columns for multiple values

Tags: excel, indexing, pivot, match, vlookup

I have a large table (50K rows) in excel with 2 columns. In col1 I have many values that repeat 5-10 times. In col2 I have values I want to transpose to columns for each value in col1. See example below (what I have vs what I need). Tried doing it with pivots and index/match but could make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: excel example]

Comment: Depending on your Excel version, you can use [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605)

Comment: I tried power query too, could not find a way to make it work. Could you share the process?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code you have tried. We'll give you a hand.

Answer (score 0):

For **Excel 365**

With data in **A1** through **B11**, in **D1** enter:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)))
```

and in **E1** enter:

```
=MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(A:A=D1,B:B,"")),SEQUENCE(,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(A:A=D1,B:B,"")))),1)
```

and copy **E1** downward:

[image]

The formula in **E1** can be reduced to:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=D1))
```

Comment: I tried but it wont let me add the FILTER funtion. It automatically suggests FILTERXML with no other option. Excel 2016 on WIn10

Comment: Also tried to import the xls into Excel 365 but it wont open it saying that the file is larger than 5MB